# How do I check my condition on an if statement to see if it is working correctly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg

I'm trying to make a type of circular display which cycles through a series of values as well as moving text elements within an svg file.  It uses the hammer.js library and uses the drag event.  The values can go in either direction.  I have it working to some degree.  As the last value is shown from an array, it goes back to the beginning of the array to get the first values.  Or vice-versa.

```
var  keyArray = ["C","C#","Db","D","D#","Eb","E","F","F#","Gb","G","G#","Ab","A","A#","Bb","B"];
```

This is my array.  Here is how I wrap it past the end of the array and back to the beginning.

** As per the request of a few commenters and the suggested solution by Nina, I have modified the code below to reflect their suggestions. I have also added a few more lines for clarity of what is happening overall.**

```
var delta = keyArray.length - 5; // can be constant, it is always positive  

for(i=0;i<5;i++){
  //5 svg text element containing 5 musical keys
  keys = document.getElementById("keys"+i);
  //ev.deltaX is the change received from the hammer pan event
  //text element moves relative to its original starting X
  keys.setAttribute("x",startingSpots[i]+ev.deltaX%150);
  currentX=keys.getAttribute("x");
  currentEdgeIndex=keyArray.indexOf(keys.textContent);    

  //This if is what appears to be failing.  
  if (keys.getAttribute("x")>=565){
    keys.setAttribute("x",currentX-150);
    keys.textContent = keyArray[(currentEdgeIndex + delta) % keyArray.length];
  }  
}
```

With the suggested changes, I removed the Number() calls as well as implementing the modulus for the wrapper.  The behavior is still erratic.  On the example below, if you pan to the right, as the first text element reaches 565, it meets the condition for the if, is moved back to the left by 150.

What it should do next is to change the textContent to the next appropriate value in the array.  However, this is where it becomes erratic, it is no longer past 565 so it does not meet the condition of the if statement, but the text changes at every increment of the pan event as if it were.

I am sure I am not seeing something simple that is causing the trouble but not sure what it is.

The array does appear to be circling correctly, though I'm still not sure "How can I check to see if the if statement is being correctly evaluated and met?"

The project can be viewed here.  http://codepen.io/cmgdesignstudios/pen/zrmQaE?editors=1010

*** Edit with solution ***
Nina suggested the problem lie in the handling of the touch event.  After further investigation, I found she was correct.  I had originally been moving the object relative to its starting position and the deltaX from the touch event.  I then was trying to change the current position by simply moving it back to the left rather than adjusting the starting position.

So I replaced the

```
keys.setAttribute("x",currentX-150);
```

with

```
startingSpots[i]-=150;
```

This kept the movement relative to the starting position and the deltaX of the touch event.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to keep calling Number() - all of those values are already numbers.

Comment: Also the `else` doesn't really need a test, it's the only other option because numbers.

Comment: I have tried the else without a condition and with, but neither appear to work.  And I do not always know when to use Number.  Often times, I end up with things begin concatenated rather than added.

Comment: _And How can I check to see if the if statement is being correctly evaluated and met?_ Simple, use the javascript debugger in your browser. Un-comment the line, load the file in the browser, set a breakpoint on the affected line and then trigger execution. Execution may be triggered on page-load, in which case you'll have to re-load the page with the break-point still set. It's debugging 101 really, do a search for a JS debugging tute for more comprehensive info.

Comment: enhzflep, I tried the debugging, but am having difficulty as the trigger is a touch event and the breakpoint breaks the touch event.  Is there a way to see and stream the watchlist variables without having a break point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please delete the `Number(...)` casting where it's not necessary. `...length` returns always number and the result of calculation is a number too.

Your actual key feature is to move 5 entries down, and this can be achieved wit a simple addition and a modulo, to keep the value in a specific range, like

```
keys.textContent = keyArray[(keyArray.length + currentEdgeIndex - 5) % keyArray.length];
```

Further simplified can this calculation then lead to just add a positive number of

```
delta = keyArray.length - 5; // can be constant, it is always positive
keys.textContent = keyArray[(currentEdgeIndex + delta) % keyArray.length];
```

and make the modulo out of it.

Comment: The code you provided did simply things quite a bit, however it produced the same erratic behavior as my previous code which makes me think it is getting into the if even when the condition is not met.  I'll update the original post with my results.

Comment: the problem you have is not with the index, it is something with the touch event, it moves faster than it should move, afaict.

Comment: I found the error with the touch event.  I'll edit the original post with the fix.  With your modulus trick, I used the `keys.textContent = keyArray[(keyArray.length + currentEdgeIndex - 5) % keyArray.length];` for movement to the right and `keys.textContent = keyArray[(keyArray.length + currentEdgeIndex + 5) % keyArray.length];` for movement to the left.